# Structure double Referencing error in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, structure

I am puzzled by the errors i get for referencing structure members.

I have structure like this,

```
typedef struct
{

    Int32      *pInAddr[2];
    Int32      a;

}JobInfo_t;

typedef struct
{

    ULUnitJobInfo_t               JobInfo[MAX_JOBS_PER_CORE];
}DispatchInfo_t;

DispatchInfo_t *ptr,temp;
ptr=&temp;
Fun(ptr) //Fun is some function
```

I pass it into the function
Fun.c as

```
Fun ( *ptr)
{
```

i get error when initializing

```
    ptr->JobInfo[0]->pInAddr[0]=0;
    ptr->JobInfo[0]->a=0;
}
```

error: expression must have pointer type

I dont know then how to access array of pointer within the structure pointer or accessing simple data (a) from structure pointer?

Another question:
If I try to access
Int32 temp= ptr->JobInfo[0].pInAddr[0];
It gives me message

"Expression must have modifiable l value"

Comment: and please learn to format your code when posting

Comment: My sincere apologies, I am new to the forum. how do u accept? i dont see any link

Comment: to accept an answer simply click the V like image next to the Answers tab you can also vote up and down or comment on all other answer. You can only accept one answer per question. Stack Overflow (SO) will remind you if you do not accept any answers but that takes some time.

There a lot more cool things, a lot of rules , rep , badges , bounties  and a ton of information. just browse around the top of the screen tabs to find all of it :)

Welcome to SO btw.

Comment: Thanks a lot Proclyon, appreciate your reply and detailed one...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JobInfo is an array of JobInfo_t, not an array of pointers.

Try that :

```
ptr->JobInfo[0].pInAddr[0]=0; ptr->JobInfo[0].a=0
```

Comment: hi nicolas, i have updated my question. I am passing structure pointer to the function. after applying your changes, ptr->JobInfo[0].a=0 now works but i still get the same error for ptr->JobInfo[0].pInAddr[0]=0

Comment: I don't now what you wanna do really. Set pInAddr[0] to null?

Comment: Hi Nicolas, I just want to initialize the array of pointers to some addresses. Array of pointer is meant to hold two address. I was trying to initialize them.